# Cancelling a coroutine internally?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I need to exit a coroutine in kotlin if a condition is not met. I would like to avoid using nested condition to keep my code clean. This is what I have:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    var condition: Boolean = false
    if (!condition) {
        //this does nothing
        this.cancel()
    }
    println("I shouldn't print")
}
```

Comment: Simply use a `return` statement.

Comment: it's a coroutine scope, not a function

Comment: It is a lambda. You can return from it using `return@launch`.

Comment: Looks like I need a visit to the docs. It worked! . Post it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

You have two ways:

1. Simply return from your coroutine body with `return@launch` statement.
2. Throw an `CancellationException` just like what `this.cancel()` does.

And the reason that your code doesn't stop working is because [Cancellation is cooperative](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative) in coroutines, your code should be cooperate with checking for `isActive` Or calling `yield()`, (just like what [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative) says) to achive such a functionality that you want

Answer (score 0):

The scope or the Job can be cancelled, but it won't affect immediately so you might still see the printed log.
`cancel()` also invokes more complex cancellationException handling.

If you're not familiar about how CancellationException works or you don't need to handle the exception state,
I'd recommend just `return@launch`.